# Tailwind dark mode toggle works but styles do not change

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a Laravel/React+Tailwind project. I have a toggle button that successfully adds the class 'dark' to my `<html>` element:

[image: Screenshot of my dev console]

However, the dark class I am using does not apply. In the next screenshot, I show how the bg-blue-100 is successfully picked up by Tailwind (onload, the default is for 'dark' to not be in the `<html>` element class list) and applied, but I have clicked on 'change theme' and therefore my `<html>` element contains the class 'dark', but the tailwind class `dark:bg-yellow-200` is not applied.

[image: screenshot]

My tailwind file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  darkMode: 'class',
  variants: ['dark', 'dark-hover', 'dark-group-hover', 'dark-even', 'dark-odd'],
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss-dark-mode')()
  ]
};
```

I've never used Tailwind before, and have near enough tried every strategy I could find when googling "react tailwind dark mode does not work". Can anyone see something wrong in my setup?

Comment: Since v2.0.0 TailwindCSS has built-in support for dark mode, there's no need to use `tailwindcss-dark-mode` plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, removing that has not fixed the issue (but at least it's one less dependency!)

Comment: Also, you can remove the `variants` entry in your config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest TailwindCSS package in NPM and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue

- From tailwind version 2 **no plugins** were required for dark theme
- Moreover as of tailwind version 3 there is no need of **purge** css

As of **tailwind@3.0.23** in the config file you need to add content:[...]

```
module.exports = {
  content: [

    //React
    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',

    //Other static file
    './static/**/*.{html}',

    //template engine
    './views/**/*.{html,pub,ejs}',

    'add your path here...'
  ],
  // ...
}
```

[Tailwind Config File](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration)